# Can I limit the Python eval() result range?

Tags: python, eval, limits

Can I limit the value range of eval()?

1. `eval('12345678**9')` returns a large number
2. `eval('1234567**8**9')` neither returns nor throws an exception

I could live with #1 but not with #2. All I need is results in the range of 32bit integers. I fear there is no way to tell eval to stop calculating too large numbers, or is there?

Comment: You can limit the value range of eval by not using eval.  Parse the string manually instead.

Comment: I guess it just takes very long to calculate.

Comment: Thanks for editing, I just tried to get there myself, too.

Comment: I found a solution by making any number a float via concatenating '.0', eval('1234567.0\*\*8.0\*\*9.0') throws an exceptions, that's fine.

Comment: The moment you call `eval()`, you have given up all control over your computer.  You may not even have a working computer afterwards - it's that dangerous.  `ast.literal_eval()` is the safe way of accomplishing this, although it is still subject to the possibility of expressions that will take forever to evaluate.

Comment: That number has over 800 million digits. You can't fit it in 32 bits

Comment: Perhaps you could fork it into a subprocess and have another process (such as the parent) set a time limit and kill if it ran too long.

Comment: of course I can't fit it in 32bits, the expressions are created by code, not by me. The point is I am only interested in results of expressions not exceeding a 'normal' range.

Comment: You can rapidly calculate the logarithm of the expression and then decline to evaluate the expression itself if the log exceeds a certain threshold.

Comment: `eval` just executes arbitrary Python expressions, so, if there is any way to limit it in Python you could probably pass such an expression to `eval`.

Comment: Perhaps you can add the answer that you found as an answer to the question. This question itself is somewhat interesting and your answer shows one way to proceed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
from math import log

def bounded_eval(expression, bits = 32):
    nums = expression.split('**')
    if len(nums) == 1:
        val = eval(expression)
        if log(val,2) > bits:
            return "too large"
        else:
            return val
    else:
        base = nums[0]
        power = '**'.join(nums[1:])
        base = eval(base)
        power = eval(power)
        if power*log(base,2) > bits:
            return "too large"
        else:
            return pow(base,power)
```

This does use `eval()` which is potentially a security risk, but if you are just calling it on arithmetical expressions that your own code generates then it isn't really a problem. Obviously, you can replace the code which returns "too large" by code which raises an error.

Comment: Yes, the expressions only consist of 9 digits and operators +,-,*,/ or **, that's all. The only danger is the results gets very large. I am a beginner in python, but not a beginner in programming.

Answer (score 1):

I've written "calculators" before using `ast` to parse the string into a tree and then walk the tree.  In this case, if you want to do some trickery, you can make this work:

```
import ast
import ctypes
import operator

def _pow(a, b):
    if isinstance(a, (ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_float, ctypes.c_double)):
        a = float(a.value)
    if isinstance(b, (ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_float, ctypes.c_double)):
        b = float(b.value)
    return ctypes.c_double(a ** b)

def _wrap_bin_op(op):
    def wrapper(a, b):
        if isinstance(a, (ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_float, ctypes.c_double)):
            a = float(a.value)
        if isinstance(b, (ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_float, ctypes.c_double)):
            b = float(b.value)
        return ctypes.c_double(op(a, b))
    return wrapper

def _wrap_unary_op(op):
    def wrapper(a):
        if isinstance(a, (ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_float)):
            a = float(a.value)
        return ctypes.c_double(op(a))
    return wrapper


_OP_MAP = {
    ast.Add: _wrap_bin_op(operator.add),
    ast.Sub: _wrap_bin_op(operator.sub),
    ast.Pow: _wrap_bin_op(operator.pow),
    ast.Mult: _wrap_bin_op(operator.mul),
    ast.Div: _wrap_bin_op(operator.truediv),
    ast.Invert: _wrap_unary_op(operator.neg),
}


class Calc(ast.NodeVisitor):

    def visit_BinOp(self, node):
        left = self.visit(node.left)
        right = self.visit(node.right)
        return _OP_MAP[type(node.op)](left, right)

    def visit_Num(self, node):
        if isinstance(node.n, int):
            val = ctypes.c_int(node.n)
        elif isinstance(node.n, float):
            val = ctypes.c_double(node.n)
        return val

    def visit_Expr(self, node):
        return self.visit(node.value)

    @classmethod
    def evaluate(cls, expression):
        tree = ast.parse(expression)
        calc = cls()
        return calc.visit(tree.body[0])


print(Calc.evaluate('12345678**8'))
print(Calc.evaluate('5 * 8'))
```

Note that unlike `eval`, I'm specifically picking and choosing what operations I want to allow -- and I have control over how they behave.  In this case, I'm doing all of my math with `ctypes` to avoid *HUGE* numbers.  I'm also preventing integer `__pow__` and forcing those arguments to become floats before raising to a specific power.

Comment: This is nice. I've used `literal_eval()` before but it only works for the simplest expressions. It is good to see how you can use the `ast` module for more involved parsing problems. +1

Comment: @JohnColeman -- Yeah, I've done this a few times.  It's pretty neat.  I'm not sure that I'm actually buying anything by using c-types in my example here because the ctypes types don't seem to provide any of the math operators that I'd expect :-/.

Answer (score 0):

As John Coleman recommended, I'll add my own solution here. Thanks for the discussion, I learned a lot about pythons capabilities.

As I commented already:

I found a solution by making any number a float via concatenating '.0', eval('1234567.0**8.0**9.0') throws an exception, that's fine.

Here's the bigger context, where this evaluation is embedded:

```
 import itertools
 digits1to8 = list(str(i+1) for i in range(8)) #('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8')

 with open("expressions.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for operators in itertools.product(['','.0+','.0-','.0*','.0/','.0**'], repeat=8):
       calculation = zip(digits1to8,operators)
       expression = (''.join(list(itertools.chain(*calculation))))+'9.0'
       try:
           out = str(eval(expression))+','
           expression = expression.replace('.0','')
           out = out.replace('.0,',',') + expression
           if (not out.find('.')>0):
               print(out, file=outfile)
       except:
           pass
```

beforehand I had ['','+','-','*','/','**'] instead of ['','.0+','.0-','.0*','.0/','.0**']. Overall this just is a little mathematical experimentation in response to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ruC5A9EzzE